# Label height won't change dynamically

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, label, constraints

I have a cell with a few labels init. One of the label is for a question. My app has different questions with different lengths. So I need my label to have a dynamical height. I want to achieve this with auto layout. When I run my app with my current auto layout it doesn't change the height (See pictures) . I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have changed the number of lines of the label to 0 and I have added:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

to my viewDidLoad(), but it won't change the height of my label.

Constraints:
[image: Auto layout]

[image: AutoLayout]

Label on device:

[image: Label on device]

Autor label Constraints:

[image: Autor label]

Bannerview Constraints:

[image: Banner view contraints]

Comment: Try this

`
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
`

Comment: I tried what are you doing and it works! Could you mention how you added constraints to the author label and the banner view?

Comment: I have added pictures how I used the constraints with the author label and the banner view!

Answer (score 0):

Set the Label height as Greater than or equal to zero in constraints. If give like this height of the label get increased based on the content.